# GCM same ID multiple times in data store after updation from getCanonicalRegistrationId Canonical IDs

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement GCM in my android app, and i have used this code for my server side implementation.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

And the implementation is working fine, and my app is able to receive the messages sent.

I installed my app and got a GCM ID, registered it with my server,and i uninstalled it and again installed it and got a new GCM id this time.

So now i send GCM messages and as a result this code(**Canonical IDs**), which updates GCM ID in data store if it receives getCanonicalRegistrationId from the result.

```
Result result = sender.send(msg, record.getRegId(), 5);

  if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
    log.info("Message sent to " + record.getRegId());
    String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
       if (canonicalRegId != null) {
          // if the regId changed, we have to update the datastore
          log.info("Registration Id changed for " + record.getRegId() + " updating to " + canonicalRegId);
          record.setRegId(canonicalRegId);
          ofy().save().entity(record).now();
       }
```

But in app-engine data store i am able to see 2 rows with same GCM ID, as after response it updates the record.

This is the image of database before sending any message, and 2 **different** GCM id are there of same device(as app was installed twice)
[image]

This is the image of database after sending messages, and 2 **same** GCM id are there (GCM ID field has equal values)

[image]

So the question is, Is this a problem, when i send messages after i have multiple record with same GCM id, as i am receiving  multiple messages in my app.And how should i try to correct it.

And when i uninstall the app, and after that i get these logs in app engine.
That the GCM ID is not present deleting it from data store, and this call is also executed multiple times.

Registration Id APA91bGn_GgXcp4L_bqwOMhmO9BRnXfjCAQgso-EbmC27L1UoNcdcPmtt5rxVMXKtW7P3_fzUNGmyMXtKBjz22iCVLiYyKPwp3uGrd8BxPlXhfQeIqYHKfyimciVXLuXdsGFvzIlIMrf no longer registered with GCM, removing from datastore

So as a result of sending multiple messages to same device, will i be using my free quota of GCM from app engine quickly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added androidId field in my table, so while registering i check, if androidId is present in the table i update the gcm id for that row, in this way i have only one row in my table even if app was installed multiple times on same device